# Running forever.js in a git bash script?

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, bash, forever

Inside my git hook post-receive file.

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/example.io/public_html --git-dir=/var/repo/example.git checkout -f
forever restart ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js
```

Then when my project is ready to be committed `git push live master` which triggers the `post-receive` script above writes the new files but forever gives me an error.

```
remote: error:   Error restarting process: ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js
remote: error:   Cannot find forever process: ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js
```

Obviously the error is clear, but I am pretty confident the directory I gave is accurate, I think I need an alternate way of telling the script where the forever process `server.js` is located.

I have read https://github.com/foreverjs/forever maybe I am missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the full path of 'forever'. In terminal run 'which forever' and use the path it gives you in your bash.

**It would look something like this**
full/path/forever restart ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js

Comment: Ah gotcha let me give it a shot!

Comment: Any idea where it is located, not quite sure where to look. Its installed on a linux server

Comment: I have found `/root/.forever/pids` I dont think thats it though?

Comment: I think its here /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever

Comment: It worked, but the permission was denied, thanks though.

Comment: I have found the path to forever but I am still not linking to the path of server.js correctly, I dont know why because it looks like its the right path.
I have used `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever restart /var/www/example.io/public_html/server.js`

Comment: I also used the path relative to the bash script `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever restart ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js`

Comment: Are you getting the same error?                                                             remote: error:   Cannot find forever process: ../../../www/example.io/public_html/server.js

Comment: Yeah I tried both, Ill try a few more times just to ensure, but yup still getting the error. I tried manually starting the script from putty from the root/ and still get an error. I think it has to be started inside the path of the server. There has to be a work around though. I hate having to log into putty then getting into my site dir and manually restarting server.js every time I make a change.